# Accelerate matrix speed in neon arm

Tags: performance, arm, matrix-multiplication, simd, neon

I tried to run the below code for 1k x 1k the time taken is 1.4s.

Is there any possible way to increase the speed and the code is tested on raspberry pi-4.

The numpy based multiply for same size taking 0.14s to execute the code.

The A and B matrix are of same size 1000 x 1000.

The code is auto-vectorized while compiling.

```c
void matrix_multiply_neon(float32_t  *A, float32_t  *B, float32_t *C, uint32_t n, uint32_t m, uint32_t k) {
    int A_idx;
    int B_idx;
    int C_idx;

    float32x4_t A0;
    float32x4_t A1;
    float32x4_t A2;
    float32x4_t A3;
  
    float32x4_t B0;
    float32x4_t B1;
    float32x4_t B2;
    float32x4_t B3;
    
    float32x4_t C0;
    float32x4_t C1;
    float32x4_t C2;
    float32x4_t C3;
    for (int i_idx=0; i_idx<n; i_idx+=4) {
            for (int j_idx=0; j_idx<m; j_idx+=4) {
                    // Zero accumulators before matrix op
                    C0 = vmovq_n_f32(0);
                    C1 = vmovq_n_f32(0);
                    C2 = vmovq_n_f32(0);
                    C3 = vmovq_n_f32(0);
                    for (int k_idx=0; k_idx<k; k_idx+=4) {
                           
                            A_idx = i_idx + n*k_idx;
                            B_idx = k*j_idx + k_idx;
                            
                            A0 = vld1q_f32(A+A_idx);
                            A1 = vld1q_f32(A+A_idx+n);
                            A2 = vld1q_f32(A+A_idx+2*n);
                            A3 = vld1q_f32(A+A_idx+3*n);
                            
                            B0 = vld1q_f32(B+B_idx);
                            C0 = vfmaq_laneq_f32(C0, A0, B0, 0);
                            C0 = vfmaq_laneq_f32(C0, A1, B0, 1);
                            C0 = vfmaq_laneq_f32(C0, A2, B0, 2);
                            C0 = vfmaq_laneq_f32(C0, A3, B0, 3);
                            B1 = vld1q_f32(B+B_idx+k);
                            C1 = vfmaq_laneq_f32(C1, A0, B1, 0);
                            C1 = vfmaq_laneq_f32(C1, A1, B1, 1);
                            C1 = vfmaq_laneq_f32(C1, A2, B1, 2);
                            C1 = vfmaq_laneq_f32(C1, A3, B1, 3);
                            B2 = vld1q_f32(B+B_idx+2*k);
                            C2 = vfmaq_laneq_f32(C2, A0, B2, 0);
                            C2 = vfmaq_laneq_f32(C2, A1, B2, 1);
                            C2 = vfmaq_laneq_f32(C2, A2, B2, 2);
                            C2 = vfmaq_laneq_f32(C2, A3, B2, 3);
                            B3 = vld1q_f32(B+B_idx+3*k);
                            C3 = vfmaq_laneq_f32(C3, A0, B3, 0);
                            C3 = vfmaq_laneq_f32(C3, A1, B3, 1);
                            C3 = vfmaq_laneq_f32(C3, A2, B3, 2);
                            C3 = vfmaq_laneq_f32(C3, A3, B3, 3);
                    }
                    // Compute base index for stores
                    C_idx = n*j_idx + i_idx;
                    vst1q_f32(C+C_idx, C0);
                    vst1q_f32(C+C_idx+n, C1);
                    vst1q_f32(C+C_idx+2*n, C2);
                    vst1q_f32(C+C_idx+3*n, C3);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you do not use a **BLAS library**? There are plenty of portable well-tested open-source very-fast implementations optimized by highly-skilled developers since decades.

Comment: yeah you are absolutely correct. I have tried with BLAS lib.That is good and worked well too. But What i want to know here is. Is there any way to increase the speed with neon intrinsics .

Comment: If this is for learning purpose, note that you can perform tiling to improve cache utilisation. Moreover your FMA are sequentially dependent reducing ILP and thus likely performance. I think bigger register blocking might help too.

Comment: To go *faster* than a good BLAS library?  Unlikely, especially for a matrix as large as 1k x 1k (big enough to hide function-call overhead and the cost of the BLAS library not being able to hard-code the exact size, like this could after inlining).  That's large enough that cache-blocking techniques will be really valueable.  If you want to learn how BLAS libraries go that fast, though, that's fine.  (e.g. cache blocking, and unrolling loops with multiple dependency chains to hide FP latency)

Comment: Note that a lot of optimizations on floats (in particular about changing ordering and breaking dependency chains) will change the output due to operation association differences. Not usually a problem, but one to be aware of.